# Different favicons for two Gmail tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

Anyone knows a way to have two Gmail inboxes with different favicons but keep the unread number icon feature?

To better distinguish the two tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible unfortunately.

I would look into a plugin that can color tabs individually so the background has a different color and you can distinquish it like that.

A few options that come to mind:

[ActivityTab Organize](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/activitytab-organize-and/pjcfilffmafkccdnheebmgnpgneackho?hl=en-US)
[DividerTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/divider-tabs/mpbblhoepkmpgalgppdoahgeoknmjgpc?hl=en-US)
[TabColorizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-colorizer-customize-y/nkdjooaecafkkldnkaokhpaindamlngj?hl=en-US)
... etc

I haven't tested these plugins, so it might not work exactly right, but this is meant as a workaround anyway, given that what you want is not possible at all anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these can preserve the unread icon number.